# Confustion with Mono.just vs then(Mono.just)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am learning reactive Java, and I am trying to do a delete operation from a database. The DB I am using is the embedded Mongo DB.

I have tried few approached to delete movie with given ID from DB and some of them works and rest dont work. Wondering I am missing some basic concepts of reactive programming.

Example 1 : Deletion Works

```
 return moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(id)
                .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build()));
```

Example 2: Deletion doest not work

```
moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(id);
return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build());
```

Example 3: Deletion does not work

```
Mono<Void> result = moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(id);
Mono<ResponseEntity> result2 = result.map(m -> ResponseEntity.noContent().build());
return result2
```

Example 4 : Deletion works

```
return moviesInfoService 
                .getMovieInfoById(id)
                .flatMap(fm -> moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(fm.getMovieInfoId()))
                .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build()));
```

I am not able to understand why in some cases deletion is working and on some not. Pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

Why its not working is because you are *breaking the chain*, and you haven't read what the operators actually do.

```
 return moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(id)
                .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build()));
```

Here `deleteMovieInfoById` returns a value, you then call the `then` operator which will (when the earlier function completes) discard that value, and instead return `ResponseEntity.noContent().build()`.

You can just write `.then(ServerResponse.noContent().build())` since `ServerResponse` will give you a `Mono` instead, or if you insist on returning a `ResponseEntity` you can instead use the `thenReturn(ResponseEntity.noContent().build())` which will wrap it in a `Mono` for you automatically.

`ResponseEntity` is from the `http` package which means its more generic, while `ServerResponse` is from the `reactive` package so its more of a convenience.

The second one does not work because if we rewrite it more exploded we get:

```
Mono<Void> someThing = moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(id);
Mono<ResponseEntity> response = Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build());
return response;
```

And as you can see here, you have two `Mono's` while one of them (the top one) is unused. In the getting started with reactor it is explained that reactor works as conveyor belt. There are two phases, the `assembly` phase and the `subscription` phase. You can read about it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription).

What this actually means is that you can't leave any mono/flux dangling, you always need to chain on the last operator, so that reactive java can react to the previous functions outcome.

You have so called *broken the chain*.

you need to chain onto `someThing`. Here i do it with `then`.

```
Mono<Void> someThing = moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(id);
Mono<ResponseEntity> response = someThing.then(ServerResponse.noContent().build());
return response;
```

Your example 3 is a bit tricker to spot, and that is because of an implicit understanding that you can't map something that is `Void`.

```
Mono<Void> result = moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(id);
Mono<ResponseEntity> result2 = result.map(m -> ResponseEntity.noContent().build());
return result2
```

In your example what would `m` be? the function before returned `Mono<Void` so `m` would be what? And that's the thing if your function before doesn't return anything, it wont run the `map` function after.

So basically `map` is not the operator to use here `then` or `thenReturn` is what should be used.

Last example works and is the most idiomatic solution.

```
return moviesInfoService 
                .getMovieInfoById(id)
                .flatMap(fm -> moviesInfoService.deleteMovieInfoById(fm.getMovieInfoId()))
                .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build()));
```

We can then rewrite this into something more verbose:

```
void Mono<ServerResponse> deleteMovie() {
    final MovieService movieService = new MovieService();
    return movieService.get("Terminator").flatMap(name -> {
        System.out.println("calling delete on: " + name);
        return movieService.delete(name);
    })
    .then(ServerResponse.noContent().build())
}

static class MovieService {

    public Mono<String> get(String s) {
        System.out.println("fetching " + s);
        return Mono.just(s);
    }

    public Mono<Void> delete(String s) {
        System.out.println("deleting " + s);
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

If you see it this way

- you are fetching something
- then calling `flatMap` on what is fetched, and this is allowed since we have something we can `flatMap` on.
- We then call `delete` inside the `flatMap` and since we are returning a `Mono<Void>` which basically just tells the reactive chain that *we are done and nothing was returned*
- we'll then only react to the completion of the last step and call `then`, where we return a `ServerResponse`.

You **always** have to chain on the last thing you did.

Most of this is explained in the [getting started with reactive programming](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive) part of the reactive documentation and you are getting downvotes because its been answered many times before here on Stack Overflow.